# Whether or not the Maass form for $\Gamma _0(N)$ on $GL(3)$ covers the classical symmetric lift of a newform on $GL(2)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I have a blur which needs some help from the experts here, and may look naive for some experts. Recently I read Zhou's paper "The Voronoi formula on $GL{(3)}$ with ramification" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.10786.pdf), where the Maass forms for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(N)$ of $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ were defined on page 5. Assume $N$ is a  prime. I wander whether or not the definition of the Maass forms of $\Gamma_0(N^2)$ covers the symmetric lift $\text{sym}^2f$ with $f$ being a newform of level $N$ on $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$?

It seems that, based on Zhou's definition, the Maass forms of $\Gamma_0(N^2)$ on $GL(3)$ is not Maass cusp form, as pointed in Remark 2.1 therein (maybe my understanding is not accurate). The introduction of Zhou's paper also referred the paper of Buttcane Jack and Rizwanur Khan's “$L^4$-norms of Hecke newforms of large level'', where the authors considered the symmetric lifts $\text{sym}^2 f$ of $GL(2)$ prime level newform $f$ as the subject.

I am not sure if the form $\text{sym}^2 f$ belongs to a Maass form defined by Zhou, observing that the form $\text{sym}^2 f$ is clearly a Maass cusp form on $GL(2)$ due to Gelbart and Jacquet' s work "A relation between automorphic representations of $GL{(2)}$ and $GL{(3)}$".

If any expert here leans something, please guide some reference or share some your very valuable comments here.
Very grateful for your time.

Much obliged, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is a Maass cusp form of prime level $N$ on $\mathrm{GL}_2$, then its symmetric square lift $\operatorname{sym}^2 f$ is a Maass cusp form of level $N^2$ on $\mathrm{GL}_3$ associated to the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(N^2)$. Zhou's definition includes cusp forms but also includes automorphic forms whose zeroeth Fourier coefficients at other cusps do not necessarily vanish.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Many thanks!